# Can NLog's variables be modified programatically if Common.Logging is in use?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog, common.logging

I have an NLog variable that I want to set the value of at runtime, in C#:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["MyVarName"] = DetermineMyVarValue();
```

But that's NLog code.  I am considering using Common.Logging rather than directly using NLog.  I do not see how to do this sort of thing through Common.Logging.  Is there a way?

Alternatively, perhaps is there a way to do it at runtime from within the NLog config file itself? So that Common.Logging can be sidestepped? For example, something like:

```
<variable name="MyVarName" value="MyStaticClass.DetermineMyVarValue()"/>
```

Preferably where that function would be called once, upon first use, rather than being called every time the variable is referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't yet found a direct answer, but I have found something that's good enough for my purposes, so I'm mentioning it here in case it might help someone in the future:

Instead of a variable, I just wrote a [custom layout renderer](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html), which is pretty straightforward.